# How to get the BLE device where I have connected in android 4.3?

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

I can scan and connect to the device, and I want to connect to multiple BLE device and list them.

I have find the getConnectedDevices(), but it has multiple type in BluetoothHeadset , BluetoothProfile and BluetoothA2dp.

**First question is **What the different between there three API ??? Which is better ??****

**I have try the code of the following:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;


    private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
                }
            }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mProListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

   }
```

I have reference the following, but I don't know how to continue.
[How to get bluetooth connected devices using BluetoothHeadset API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509135/how-to-get-bluetooth-connected-devices-using-bluetoothheadset-api)

**Second question:**

Where should I type the `List<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();` in??

**Third question**

Can I click the device which list by getConnectedDevices() and operation after I click such as `setOnItemClickListener` ??

I'm new to this. Thanks for everyone's direction.

Comment: Did you found the solution of your question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get bluetooth connected devices using BluetoothHeadset API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509135/how-to-get-bluetooth-connected-devices-using-bluetoothheadset-api)