# How to get bluetooth device connecting in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

How to get name and address of bluetooth device connecting with my device in android when start my activity ? Not get bluetooth device when found .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get bluetooth connected devices using BluetoothHeadset API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509135/how-to-get-bluetooth-connected-devices-using-bluetoothheadset-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
```

If you have set up a bluetooth set and array then this will add it to a list view.