# How to get connected Bluetooth device to App?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am getting all paired and connected Bluetooth device list from getBoundedDevice. But i need only connected devices.my code is here

```
  final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
  for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices){    
  Log.e("Paired Devices", bt.getName()+"");
  }
```

Comment: You may find this link helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590

Comment: @blueware, Thanks for your response. I have got solution from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341718/connection-to-specific-hid-profile-bluetooth-device

Comment: Most welcome, glad to know that you got it sorted.