# BroadcastReceiver not called at launch

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I need to detect when wired headset or a bluetooth one is plugged/connected so I create and register two `BroadcastReceiver`(s) like the following:

**file ReceiverHeadsetWired.java**

```
public class ReceiverHeadsetWired extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ActivityMain main;

    public ReceiverHeadsetWired(
        ActivityMain activityMain
    ){
        main = activityMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(
        Context context,
        Intent intent
    ) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getAction())) { return; }

        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), "android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG")) {
            Log.d("[ReceiverHeadsetWired]", "onReceive()");
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**file ReceiverHeadsetBluetooth.java**

```
public class ReceiverHeadsetBluetooth extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ActivityMain main;

    public ReceiverHeadsetBluetooth(
        ActivityMain activityMain
    ){
        main = activityMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(
        Context context,
        Intent intent
    ) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getAction())) { return; }

        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), "android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED")) {
            Log.d("[ReceiverHeadsetBluetooth]", "onReceive()");
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them are dynamically registered in `onCreate` method of MainActivity's Fragment and unregisterd `onDestroy`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(
    Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    ActivityMain main = (ActivityMain) getActivity();

    ...
    
    registerHeadsetWiredReceiver();

    registerHeadsetBluetoothReceiver();

    ...     

}


private void registerHeadsetWiredReceiver() {
    wiredHeadsetReceiver = new ReceiverHeadsetWired(main);
    IntentFilter hwFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
    main.registerReceiver(wiredHeadsetReceiver, hwFilter);
}

private void registerHeadsetBluetoothReceiver() {
    bluetoothHeadsetReceiver = new ReceiverHeadsetBluetooth(main);
    IntentFilter hbFilter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED");
    main.registerReceiver(bluetoothHeadsetReceiver, hbFilter);
}
```

Now the point is that at launch only the `onReceive` of **ReceiverHeadsetWired** is called (Logcat shows the textline), but after app started both of them work as expected except a strange behaviour: the first time I connect a Bluetooth headset the related Log is written twice.

In other words when app is launched if a wired headset is plugged it will be detected but a connected bluetooth one won't.

Does anybody knows what's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Detect if bluetooth headset connected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629557/10534012)

Comment: @Darkman thanks, it's ok it works but I'm also interested in understanding why my solution has that strange bahaviour; any idea? thanks

Comment: oops, ctrl+c ctrl+v is often tricky, actually in the "real world" there's *android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED*, just made mistake writing SO question

Comment: question edited

Comment: Try using a diff filter like `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED`. All filters are available [here](https://gist.github.com/pwittchen/1aba5f9a1f71d7770f76). If it doesn't work, then you're of out luck.