# How to get bluetooth profiles status in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-bluetooth, android-broadcast

Is there anyway to get the bluetooth profiles status programatically?

Comment: You can from anroid documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the connected device Blue tooth profiles status from another application in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525862/how-to-get-the-connected-device-blue-tooth-profiles-status-from-another-applicat)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509135/how-to-get-bluetooth-connected-devices-using-bluetoothheadset-api

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        System.out.println("Device does not support Bluetooth");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Status " + mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());
    }
```

based on : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html