# How to get the connected BT device Address in Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

In my mobile app i have to get the connected BT address and start SPP connection. Is there any way to get the connected BT device address?

Answer (score 0):

Following may be help you

```
public void getDeviceList(){
        BluetoothAdapter mBlurAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBlurAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e("DeviceActivity ",
                    "Device not founds");
            return ;
        }

        for (BluetoothDevice devices : pairedDevices) {
            Log.d("DeviceActivity", "Device : address : " + devices.getAddress() + " name :"
                    + devices.getName());
        }
    }
```

Also don't miss to define permission

Comment: the above code will give the paired device list. I want the currently connected bluetooth device address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509135/how-to-get-bluetooth-connected-devices-using-bluetoothheadset-api this may be help you