# How to get the details from Bluetooth headset when bluetooth connected to mobile in android studio

Tags: java, android

Connected Bluetooth headset to the mobile and I want get the details from the BT headset using android studio

I can't detect bluetooth headset details to the android application

Comment: which details exactly? `I can't detect bluetooth headset details` why?

Comment: bluetooth headset's deviceName and deviceAddress throught the mobile bluetooth settings get into the android application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578825/1568530 this answer shows how to find the list of connected devices. `BluetoothDevice` has both - name and address

Comment: List<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();                        
for ( final BluetoothDevice dev : devices ) {           
     return mBluetoothHeadset.isAudioConnected(dev);
}

Comment: above the code..can get the bluetooth headset details

Comment: Hello vladyslav-matviienko, thanks for helping , But till I not getting result. you given code not working properly

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: you wrote that `can get the bluetooth headset details`